# uniq cluster name

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, command-line

We have several clustered servers and need to check 1 server in each cluster. How do I compare entries in a list to return only one server in each cluster?
All server names follow [a-z]-[a-z]-[a-z][0-9].domain_name

Example server list.

```
test-rac-1.domain_name
test-rac-2.domain_name
test-rac-3.domain_name
test-rac-dg1.domain_name
test-rac-dg2.domain_name
test-rac-dg3.domain_name
qat-rac-1.domain_name
qat-rac-2.domain_name
qat-rac-3.domain_name
ser-ser-ser.domain_name
long-serv-name.domain_name
```

Result server list.

```
test-rac-1.domain_name
test-rac-dg1.domain_name
qat-rac-1.domain_name
ser-ser-ser.domain_name
long-serv-name.domain_name
```

-- result can be any of the servers in the cluster.

Comment: There is no name in your list that matches `[a-z]-[a-z]-[a-z][0-9].domain_name`.  Did you mean `[a-z]+-[a-z]+-[a-z0-9]+\.domain_name` (as an extended regular expression)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter all lines with grep using a regex.

```
grep '[a-z-]1\?\.domain_name' file > newfile
```

This returns all lines with letters or minus and an optional `1` before ".domain_name".

---

The inverse operation would be to remove all lines containing numbers > 1 before ".domain_name":

```
grep -v '\([2-9]\|[0-9]1\)\.domain_name' file > newfile
```

This matches lines with 2 to 9 as last digit before ".domain_name" or numbers with at least two digits where the last digit is `1` (to match 11 or 21 etc). The `-v` option is used to select non-matching lines.

Comment: Freddy, Thanks for the quick reply. Your answer solved it! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you can't be certain that each cluster contains a host numbered `1`, you'll need to keep track of the clusters you've already seen.  In `awk` (among others) you can do that with an associative array:

```
awk '{o=$0; sub(/[0-9]+/,"",o)} !a[o]++ {print}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Freddy's answer only gives the first node from each. While that might be all you need, this picks a random node from each cluster instead.

```
# iterate through unique list of cluster stub names, assuming a digit marks the node number
for cluster in $(sed -e 's/.domain_name//' serverlist|tr -d '[[:digit:]]'|sort -u)
  do
  # for this cluster, get the list of all node names if indexed
  nodes=( $(grep $cluster'[[:digit:]]' serverlist) )
  # if there wasn't a match it's because it's a cluster of one without a node number
  if (( ${#nodes[@]} == 0 )); then
    # cluster of one
    echo $cluster
  else
    # pick a random number from 1 to number of nodes
    # subtract one to make it an array index
    n=$(( $(shuf -i"1-${#nodes[@]}" -n1) -1 ))
    echo ${nodes[$n]}
  fi
done
```

Comment: I'm also being rude about your `domain_name` - I don't care if they're all the same.